# Are there any ways to increase the number of items I can attune to without being an Artificer?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attunement

The problem is quite simple: I want to attune to four or more magical items at once, and I don't want to [take ten levels in Artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#MagicItemAdept-1134228) (the [rules for attunement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement) permit a maximum of three attuned items).

Are there any features, items, etc. that increase the number of items you can attune to without being a 10th level or higher artificer?

Comment: I assume you want an answer for the general case, and that *you* specifically have to be attuned to these items and benefit from them all exactly simultaneously? So methods that work with particular items, having a familiar attune to items for you, and methods of reducing the time it takes to attune to a new item, do not count?

Comment: @Medix2 Correct, I, Thomas, want to attune to four items without being an Artificer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Get possessed by a Trickster God

From the [Temple of the Nine Gods](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/tomb-of-the-nine-gods#SpiritsoftheNineTricksterGods) in *Tomb of Annihilation* there are Trickster Gods. Leaving the process of how to get possessed to the adventure book (hint: you'll want to fail a saving throw) you want to get possessed by Obo’laka for her granted power of:

> The host can attune to one additional magic item. When Obo’laka leaves the host, all magic items to which the host is attuned are no longer attuned to it.

Possession by trickster gods are done at the adventurer's own risk.

---

There's also an honorable mention of just being [Jarlaxle Baenre](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/jarlaxle-baenre) (of *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* fame) who has a trait called Master Attuner:

> Jarlaxle can attune to up to five magic items, and he can attune to magic items that normally require attunement by a sorcerer, warlock, or wizard.

However there are no ways, as far as I know, to transform yourself into him nor to obtain the trait as a PC (outside of unadulterated DM-fiat).

Comment: unless Jarlaxle is his own species, in which case you could True Polymorph into an average member (hehe) of him / his species. Sadly, he at best fathered a new subspecies of Half-Drow-Dragons.

Comment: @PixelMaster Jarlaxle is a drow.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I know ("Half-Drow-Dragons"). It was meant to be a joke, though that doesn't seem to have worked out very well, if I have to explain it ^^ I suppose I should have written "if Jarlaxle was his own species" to be grammatically correct & maybe make it clearer ^^

Comment: I believe the *magic jar* spell would work here. Time to *magic jar* Jarlaxle!