# Would an item that provided an extra attunement slot be unbalanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, equipment, attunement

I am PC in a extremely high magic campaign. I am a level five character, and I have already used up all three of my attunement slots. My DM is fine with homebrew.

My question is would a magic item that increased the number of attunement slots you have by two, and does require attunement be too powerful?

There could be a prereq that you must have a constitution of at least 16. And there would have to be something that stops someone from attuning to more that one of these.

I have seen the other question that is similar to this one that ask if there are any items, but I am asking if such a item would be to powerful.

Comment: Related: [Are there any ways I can increase the number of items I can attune to without being an Artificer?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/182096/are-there-any-ways-to-increase-the-number-of-items-i-can-attune-to-without-being)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### The *Dungeon Master's Guide* recommends against doing this

The intro to Chapter 9 of the *DMG*, ["Dungeon Master's Workshop"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#DungeonMastersWorkshop), states (on page 263):

> [...]
>
> Beware of adding anything to your game that allows a character to concentrate on more than one effect at a time, use more than one reaction or bonus action per round, or attune to more than three magic items at a time. Rules and game elements that override the rules for concentration, reactions, bonus actions, and magic item attunement can seriously unbalance or overcomplicate your game.

---

#### Artificers can do it, but that's their whole schtick

The [Artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer) class gains an additional attunement slot at levels 10, 14, and 18. These features ([Magic Item Adept](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#MagicItemAdept-1134228), [Magic Item Savant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#MagicItemSavant-1134349), and [Magic Item Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#MagicItemMaster-1134372)) are *incredibly* strong, especially at 14th level when they gain the ability to ignore most prerequisites for attunement. But magic items is the Artificer's entire *thing*; it's what they *do*, and they do it *very* well. The class *creates* magic items, and giving them more attunement slots couples with this nicely, *incredibly* nicely. I've seen these features, and they are *strong*; I caution against giving them out to other characters, especially when this would step on the toes of another class that *thrives* with magic items.

---

#### Playtesting is always a good idea

At the end of the day, regardless of what I, the *DMG*, or Artificers say, the best way to determine if a change is too strong *for your campaign* is to playtest it. To throw it in and see where it goes, see what your players do with it (maybe even what the enemies do with it.) Because, while we can make sophisticated guesses or I can speak to my own experiences *at my own tables*, those are *my* tables. My players might not capitalize on a rule the same way yours would and the item may impact my worlds in ways vastly different from yours. So I'll repeat my usual advice with homebrew: Playtest, playtest, playtest.

---

Of note, if you *do* implement this item, you don't need to add anything to prevent somebody from attuning to more than one. The [attunement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement) rules have you covered:

> Additionally, a creature can't attune to more than one copy of an item. For example, a creature can't attune to more than one ring of protection at a time.

Also of note, if you make an item that requires attunement and increases the number of attunement slots available by *one*, *that* item is almost certainly balanced, what with its exceedingly few use-cases.

Comment: This is, of course, what the rules themselves say. Ignoring the fact that Wizards themselves tend to unbalance their own game, this doesn't really answer the question "Will the game break if I allow this?" It just says "The book says things will break." Did it break a game you were running / playing? You allude to your own tables but don't elaborate. A houserule I've seen often online is to allow attuned items up to proficiency.

Comment: @Jason_c_o "I've seen these features, and they are strong; I caution against giving them out to other characters, especially when this would step on the toes of another class that thrives with magic items. [...] the best way to determine if a change is too strong for your campaign is to playtest it. [...] I can speak to my own experiences at my own tables, those are my tables. My players might not capitalize on a rule the same way yours would and the item may impact my worlds in ways vastly different from yours." In short, yes, I *have* seen having more than 3 attunement slots "break" games

Comment: That, to me, is the experience that needs to be emphasized within the answer. How did it break?

Comment: @Jason_c_o I'm alright with how it's emphasized already, and will probably be leaving it as-is, but I do appreciate the advice